# React - How to use a key to setState on a specific object in an array when modifying a property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-props, react-dom

I have created a menu card that will show a card for each object in an array. The object holds details about that menu item. I am looking to affect one property of that menu item but I am unsure how to potentially use the key or an id to affect only that item. How can I dynamically select an object from an array based on its key or some other unique identifier?

Right now as a stand-in I use handleCategory to affect the first object in the array. I am looking instead to affect the object based on which Item card I am using.

Below is what my code looks like (basic example):

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Items from './items'
import Navbar from './navbar'

class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            value: 'enter',
            condimentCount: 5,
            menuItems: [
                {
                    "id": 1234,
                    "item_name": 'chow mein',
                    "category_id": 'meal'
                },
                {
                    "id": 1235,
                    "item_name": '',
                    "category_id": 'meal'
                }
            ]
        };
            this.handleCategory = this.handleCategory.bind(this);
    }



    handleCategory = (event, id) => {
        console.log('changing meal type', event.target.value)
        //this.setState({value: event.target.value});

        // 1. Make a shallow copy of the items
         let items = [...this.state.menuItems];
        // 2. Make a shallow copy of the item you want to mutate
         let item = {...items[0]};
        // 3. Replace the property you're intested in
         item.category_id = event.target.value;
        // 4. Put it back into our array. N.B. we *are* mutating the array here, but that's why we made a copy first
         items[0] = item;
        // 5. Set the state to our new copy
         this.setState({menuItems: items});
    }



    render() {

        let menuItems = null;
        if (this.state.menuItems) {
            menuItems = (
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.menuItems.map((item, i) => {
                            return <div key={i}>
                                <MenuItem
                                    key={item.id} //IS THIS CORRECT?
                                    item_name={item.item_name}
                                    category_id={item.category_id}
                                    handleCategory={this.handleCategory}
                                />
                            </div>
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            )
        }

        return (

            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <div>
                    {Items}
                </div>


            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

**Items.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './items.module.css'

const Items = (props) => {


    return (
        <div className={classes.cards}>
                <form>
                    <label>
                        What kind of meal item is this (e.g. meal, drink, side):
                        <select value={props.category_id} onChange={props.handleCategory}>
                            <option value="meal">meal</option>
                            <option value="drink">drink</option>
                            <option value="side">side</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </form
        </div>
    )
}

export default Items;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do in `handleCategory`, but I understand your question I believe.

You can use the index from `map` to access the menu items in `handleCategory`.

```js
this.state.menuItems.map((item, i) => {
  return <div key={i}>
    <MenuItem
      item_name={item.item_name}
      category_id={item.category_id}
      handleCategory={e => this.handleCategory(e, i)}
    />
  </div>
})
```

Comment: this is super helpful. Basically you got my question . I will replace the 0 in `handleCategory ` with `key` so that only that object is affected. Thanks!

Comment: @LoF10 I don't know what you mean by `key`. It would just be a `i` or `index`. ie. Change the function to `handleCategory = (event, index) => {`.